# Remove items in database based on status of checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to take input from an HTML form where there are checkboxes. The checkboxes are created with the student_ids from the database. Like so:

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="{$row['STUDENT_ID']}" />
```

What I want to do is step through the Students table and check all of the entries against which of the checkboxes are checked. I want to then delete the entries from the database that have been checked with the checkboxes.

```
  8    $query = "SELECT STUDENT_ID From Students";
  9 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 10 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 11   $checkname=$row['STUDENT_ID'];
 12   foreach($_POST[$checkname] as $student_id =>val)
 13   {
 14   if($val == 'YES'
 15     {
 16       echo $_POST['STUDENT_ID'];
 17       $query = "DELETE FROM Students WHERE STUDENT_ID" . mysql_real_escape_string($STUDENT_ID);
 18     }
 19   echo $query;
 20   $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 21   //echo $POST['STUDENT_ID'];
 22 }
 23 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of checkbox :

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="studentID[]" value="{$row['STUDENT_ID']}" />
```

From PHP :

```
    $studentID = $_POST['studentID'];

    foreach($studentID as $ID){
        echo $ID.'<br />'."\n";
    }
```

EDIT :
Not sure but I think this is the right way :

```
    $studentID = $_POST['studentID'];

    $i=0;
    foreach($studentID as $ID){
        $i++;
        echo $_POST['studentID'][$i].'<br />'."\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="STUDENT_ID[<?php echo $row['STUDENT_ID'] ?>]" value="YES" />
```

and this for your PHP loop:

```
foreach ($_POST['STUDENT_ID'] as $student_id => $val) {
    if ($val == 'YES') {
        $query = "DELETE FROM Students WHERE STUDENT_ID=" . mysql_real_escape_string($student_id);
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way of doing this is to take the Student IDs from your checkboxes that were submitted and then run deletes on those.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="students_to_delete[]" value="{$row['STUDENT_ID']}" />
```

PHP

```
$students_to_delete = $_POST['students_to_delete'];
if(is_array($students_to_delete) && count($students_to_delete) > 0) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM Students WHERE STUDENT_ID IN (" . implode(",", $students_to_delete) . ")";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code is vulnerable to SQL injection. If someone posts back to the server a value of `0 OR STUDENT_ID!=0` then all rows in the Students table will be deleted.

Your code is also inefficient - you are returning all the students and then iterating over each student to see if this requires deleting.

You would be better using in your markup:

`<input type="checkbox" name="STUDENT_TO_DELETE" value="$row['STUDENT_ID']" />`

and then in the php:

`foreach ($_POST['STUDENT_TO_DELETE'] as $student_id => $val) {

        $sql = "DELETE FROM Students WHERE STUDENT_ID=" . mysql_real_escape_string($student_id); 
        mysql_query($sql);
    } 
}`